# Create a simple Google chart using PHP server-side

Tags: php, google-visualization

I've already did all the step to configure the Analytics account and when I run the example I get the correct result (a string showing the name of the account and the last 30 days visit count), what I want now is to display some basic data using a Google chart.
The code I'm using is the following:

```
<?php

function getService()
{
  // Creates and returns the Analytics service object.

  // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
  require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

  // Use the developers console and replace the values with your
  // service account email, and relative location of your key file.
  $service_account_email = '***';
  $key_file_location = 'client_secrets.p12';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("HelloAnalytics");
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

  // Read the generated client_secrets.p12 key.
  $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
  $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
      $service_account_email,
      array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
      $key
  );
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
  if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
  }

  return $analytics;
}

function getFirstprofileId(&$analytics) {
  // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

  // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
  $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

  if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
    $items = $accounts->getItems();
    $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

    // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
    $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
        ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

    if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
      $items = $properties->getItems();
      $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

      // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
      $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
          ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

      if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $profiles->getItems();

        // Return the first view (profile) ID.
        return $items[0]->getId();

      } else {
        throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
      }
    } else {
      throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
  }
}

function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:***',
       '30daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults(&$results) {
  // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
  // the profile name and total sessions.
  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    // Get the profile name.
    $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

    // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
    $rows = $results->getRows();
    $sessions = $rows[0][0];

    // Print the results.
    print "First view (profile) found: $profileName\n";
    print "Total sessions: $sessions\n";
  } else {
    print "No results found.\n";
  }
}

$analytics = getService();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
printResults($results);

?>
```

Is there any example that shows how to populate a Chart parsing the correct data?

On the Google docs I wasn't able to find anything, What I want it's like this example:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/

But it uses Python instead of PHP